# How to split a list of tuples based on inner element value

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples of elements like this:

```
[
('All', 1, 0.6, 5.0),
('right,', 1, 0.6, 5.0),
("let's", 1, 0.6, 5.0),
('get', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('the', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('clock', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('up', 0, 0.36, 5.0), 
('here.', 0, 0.36, 5.0)
]
```

I want to split this list into two lists whenever the 1st element changes. The result should be like this:

```
[
('All', 1, 0.6, 5.0),
('right,', 1, 0.6, 5.0),
("let's", 1, 0.6, 5.0)
],
[
('get', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('the', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('clock', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('up', 0, 0.36, 5.0), 
('here.', 0, 0.36, 5.0)
]
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: the second element - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

Assuming the input list as `l`:

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(g) for k,g in groupby(l, lambda x: x[1])]
```

output:

```
[[('All', 1, 0.6, 5.0), ('right,', 1, 0.6, 5.0), ("let's", 1, 0.6, 5.0)],
 [('get', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('the', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('clock', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('up', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('here.', 0, 0.36, 5.0)]
]
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but this assumes that g is ordered by x[1]

Comment: @SurDin Not necessarily, the request is to split upon change of value. `groupby` splits on changed value, which is exactly the use case here. You would need to sort if you want to make unique groups per key.

Comment: They said split into 2 lists, so I'm not exactly sure what the request is exactly

Comment: I imagine the "*two*" relates to this specific case, the logic wouldn't make sense otherwise, but I might be wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

mozway surely beat me but here's a solution that doesn't use libraries. It uses dictionaries!

```
lst = [...]    # contains your list

dct = {}

for tpl in lst: 
    idx = tpl[1]               # idx has the 'dependent' variable
    temp = dct.get(idx, [])
    temp.append(tpl)
    dct[idx] = temp
    
print(list(dct.values()))

print(dct.keys())
```

Comment: `itertools` is part of the standard library, this is not an exotic dependency ;) nice solution otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I used a list comprehension just to make it a single line statement.

Assumed that the entries change are 0 or 1.

```
lst = [
('All', 1, 0.6, 5.0),
('right,', 1, 0.6, 5.0),
("let's", 1, 0.6, 5.0),
('get', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('the', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('clock', 0, 0.36, 5.0),
('up', 0, 0.36, 5.0), 
('here.', 0, 0.36, 5.0)
]


new_lst = [[], []]

[new_lst[0].append(i) if i[1] == 0 else new_lst[1].append(i) for i in lst]

print(new_lst)
```

Output

```
[[('get', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('the', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('clock', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('up', 0, 0.36, 5.0), ('here.', 0, 0.36, 5.0)], [('All', 1, 0.6, 5.0), ('right,', 1, 0.6, 5.0), ("let's", 1, 0.6, 5.0)]]
```